# Do I need a snubber in a snubberless triac?

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, triac, inductive, snubber

I am trying to make this circuit and using the Triac as a switch. I am using in this one a BTA06, although I will upgrade it to a BTA12 so it can handle 220 V 1000 W easily. It will be implemented in a UPS, so is this circuit OK to control the two triacs using MOC3061 zero crossing ICs? Is it OK to hook an inductive load as a motor to the triacs? Would I still need a snubber circuit for the triacs?

[image]

Comment: of course, mate.

Comment: What are all the connections here? "MOS-Inverter" seems to imply something quite important. Why are TER7, TER8, etc. labeled the same between the two diagrams? Are they actually connected?

Comment: @TimWilliams  MOS-Inverter isn't really important it is the DC side it is connected to a MOSFET but what matters in the question is the AC side. Yes all of those are connected together like the optocoupler U4 pin 6 is connected with a resistor in series to "TER8" and "TER8" is the same T3 second terminal.

Comment: You may get more input if the schematic is redrawn to clarify connectivity.  You may also get more input if you explain what you're trying to do, why you want to use multiple TRIACs, what the named nets are, how they're driven, etc. etc.

Comment: I get you mate I will remove the question and renew it. Thanks.